# How do I scrape the following linked datepicker pop-up with google chrome web scraper?

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping

I know absolutely nothing about coding. I am working on a personal project that deals with importing large
amounts of data from the website:
(https://masslottery.com/games/keno.html)
I am trying to copy and paste every keno draw (over 2 million) into
excel spread sheet's to analyze the data, and if not all of them then
at least the past 10 years. Up until yesterday I've been copy, and
pasting 300 draws at a time, and I have the past 220,000 draws
imported that goes back to September of 2017 which has been extremely
tedious, as well as time consuming
I recently learned that I can do all this in MUCH LESS time by
scraping the website, and in researching how to do this, it brought me
across a You Tube video that I must say was extremely insightful which dealt with scraping websites with google chrome scape
Now referring to the website link I've attached, it lets you "Search
Past Numbers by Draw Date," and after clicking on the white insert a
calendar pops up where after "Inspecting" the page I've come to find
out it's a "datepicker widget," (I believe), so my question is... How
do you Scrape the data thru the datepicker? This is all new to me, so
if you could explain it in layman terms then that would be great.
I appreciate you all taking the time to read about my question, and if it's no
inconvenience could you help me with this question. If it would be
easier for you to just send me the data then explain it all then OF
COURSE!!... by all means that would be perfectly fine by me as well.
HAHAHAHA But to be honest after learning about web scraping, it's probably is quicker for you.
Well again... Thank you for your help

Comment: You can start without coding at first, scraping is more about understanding how data is retrieved from the server, coding is just to automate the process. Let's take your site, open it in a new tab on Chrome, go to the page where you have the data you want, open the developper tools on that tab (more tools > developper tools). Click on the network tabs & refresh the page, you can now see all pages loaded by the site. Your data is here in those pages. Get some info/tutorial on the web about the developper tools if you don't know what the Headers/Preview & Response tabs are.

Comment: For instance just looking at the page loaded, I've found this one : https://masslottery.com/data/json/search/dailygames/history/15/201910.json . Look at the URL ending with 201910 which is for october 2019, try updating the URL with 201909 you have september. This format is JSON format (google it on the web). I'm sure you can find some tutorial online to help you with automating the extraction

Comment: @BertrandMartel Thank you for your assistance. It was greatly appreciated... After much research I found that all the data is organized by month and year, so each month has it's own web page with the data stored on it for each draw in that month which depending on the number of days averages out to 9,000 draws a month for a 30 day month.

Comment: In reference to the link you provided: https://masslottery.com/data/json/search/dailygames/history/15/201910.json which ends in: /201910 because it is all the data for October 2019, so the data for August 2017 will end in: /201708 for the year and month. Now how do I scrape all the data off these pages. Do I do them individually, or is there a way to do them all at once? And then the next question is; How do I go about this with chrome web scrape? Because as I stated beforeI don't know much about programming or scraping data.